# Use react proptypes for validation in purely functional code

Tags: javascript, validation, reactjs

I really like the idea of react proptypes and am wondering if they can be used to validate the input of any given function, not just the props being passed to a react component.

For example:

```
function doSomething (thing1, thing2) {
    Proptypes.validate(arguments, [Proptypes.string, Proptypes.number]);
}
```

Is there a way of getting proptypes to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you envisioning `validate` would do? You're not planning on using *exceptions* in your "purely functional code", are you? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Ideally this would be a way to do type checking during development, to make sure that the arguments to a function are actually of the correct type. It would also serve as a sort of documentation.

Comment: Oh, and it would be nice to be able to remove it completely when running the code in production!

Comment: Maybe you'd be interested in [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/)?

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I necessarily want because I don't think it is able to give errors if a module is being used from another file. Like say I call a function from a separate file and pass incorrect data, I don't think the typescript would catch that currently..? Maybe I'm wrong about that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes they can although you'll need to pass some extraneous params.

You'd probably want to do a wrapper function to make life easier but, don't forget that the `React.PropTypes` are just functions themselves.

For example:

```
React.PropTypes.string(props, propName, componentName)
```

Where `props` is the entire props object for a component, `propName` is the name (and key) of the prop being checked, and `componentName` is the name of the component you're calling it from.

Although I think it would probably be better to roll your own as it would be a very small amount of code to do this yourself and it would shield you against any potential changes to how `React.PropTypes` work in future versions of React.

Comment: Do you know if anyone has already written such a wrapper? It seems like validating the arguments of a function would be a very generic need.

Comment: Not sure, I've usually written my own in various projects due to needs being slightly different each time.  In sure someone must have made a generic one though!

Answer (score 1):

Prop validators are functions, so you can just call them. As the `customProp` example in the [Prop Validation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#prop-validation) doc illustrates, the arguments are `props`, `propName`, and `componentName`. The function returns `null` on success or an `Error` on failure. For example:

```
React.PropTypes.number({'a': 4}, 'a', 'foo')
// null

React.PropTypes.number({'a': 'b'}, 'a', 'foo')
// Error: Invalid undefined `a` of type `string`
// supplied to `foo`, expected `number`
```